# SQL Server credentials - Maximum Password size

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, password

What's the maximum password size I can get on SQL Server 2012/2014? I was unable to find this information online.

I mean SQL Server credentials itself, not passwords inside tables.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you clarify whether it's SQL Server or SQL Azure your talking about, please?  They are different products with differing constraints and abilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Passwords are case-sensitive. **Passwords should always be at least 8
>   characters long, and cannot exceed 128 characters.** Passwords can
>   include a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and most non-alphanumeric characters. Passwords
>   cannot contain single quotes, or the login_name.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx